# Autoreleasepool memory leak?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm new to Xcode 4.2 and since my project is almost finished, I thought I'd try some of the Instruments Apple provides. So, I ran Leak, and apparently, it found a leak directly at the app start. I get a solid orange vertical bar in the "Leaks" section, and when I investigate, it appears that this is the culprit:

```
    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        @autoreleasepool {
//problem appears on the line below in Orange
            return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TestProjectAppDelegate class]));
        }
    }
```

Since I'm new to this, I have no idea what the problem is, how to solve it, or even if I'm finding the actual issue!

(Isn't there supposed to be a "drain" call somewhere?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT
Link to screenshot file: http://whoit.home.comcast.net/~whoit/combined.jpg
(too big to embed)

Comment: Have you tried drilling down through the Instruments display?

Comment: Yes, but since I'm new to this, it doesn't really mean anything to me.

Comment: Unfortunately - since I can't see you screen - It means nothing to me, either.

Comment: @Abizern I can add detail to my initial post - text or screenshots?

Comment: I think that would be helpful.

Comment: `@autoreleasepool { ... }` is equivalent to `NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new]; ... [pool drain];`

Comment: But the problem is that you're returning without hitting the closing `}`.  Not that it matters from a functional standpoint, since the whole app's storage system will be disposed momentarily, but you can assign the return code from UIApplicationMain to a temp, close the autorelease range, and then return on the temp to eliminate the warning messages.

Comment: @Abizern OK, I just added a link to my original post for the screenshot image. Thanks.

Comment: @HotLicks - According to the documentation, returning should not be a problem.  Keep in mind this is a compiler construct, not a normal block.  From Apple docs "On entry, an autorelease pool is pushed. On normal exit (break, return, goto, fall-through, and so on) the autorelease pool is popped."

Comment: FYI - the code in my original post was automatically generated when I created my project in Xcode 4.2...

Answer (score 2):

Click `invert call tree` in Leak's option pane.

And also, maybe you could add the screenshot for this view if possible:

[image: Leaks]

Comment: Would you mind attaching some screenshots after expanding those call trees in Leaks?

Comment: OK, I just added a link to my original post for the screenshot image. Thanks.

Comment: Would you please also attach Leaks view, which is parallell to Cycles & root, call tree and console?

Comment: I believe the Leaks view is at the top-left of the jpg. Or are you referring to the horizontal timeline across the top of the window (also called "Leaks" !) ?

Comment: It's a vertical pop-up menu, listing options `Leaks`, `Cycles & Roots`, `Call tree` and `Console`. In your previous screenshot, the `Call tree` was selected.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the entire @autoreleasepool block with this:

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([TestProjectAppDelegate class]));
[pool release];

return retVal;
```

If you still see the same leak, then you've got an over-retain issue somewhere else in your code and this section is not the issue.  If you *don't* still see it (unlikely), then there could be something wrong with this new language construct.  Highly unlikely, but this IS a new construct so there could certainly be bugs.

Comment: Can't do it - I'm using ARC and the compiler complains about your code.

Comment: @wayneh - Ah, right it would if you're using ARC.  It's also possible that the leaks tool is not completely updated to be aware of the new ARC system, and is falsely reporting a leak.